# What's the meaning of "il/elle temporise" ?

Tags: sens

I have a doubt on the exact meaning of "temporiser" in the following contexts :

> Amandine est en quelque sorte une « artiste de la chaussure ». Même si elle **temporise** : « Artiste, je ne sais pas. Mais j’ai toujours baigné là-dedans », sourit la Nordiste.
> -- ([source](https://actu.fr/hauts-de-france/mons-en-baroeul_59410/avec-doodle-me-amandine-customise-vos-sneakers-a-la-main-dans-la-metropole-de-lille_53979469.html))

> On observe une situation similaire à celle de l’année dernière à la même époque. Cet épisode caniculaire est relativement long pour la saison. Il dure quasiment une semaine », note Robert Vautard, directeur de l’Institut Pierre Simon Laplace des sciences du climat et spécialiste des événements extrêmes. Il **temporise** : « Cela ne veut pas forcément dire qu’on va repartir comme l’année dernière mais il y a des conditions favorables aux chaleurs extrêmes et aux départs de feu. La météo est capricieuse… »
> -- ([source](https://www.la-croix.com/Monde/Climat-lAustralie-est-elle-nouveau-point-sembraser-2020-12-01-1201127566))

> Arnaud regrette de ne pas avoir connu Élodie plus tôt. Elle **temporise** : « on s’est connu au bon moment ! »  -- ([source](https://rennes.maville.com/actu/actudet_-pres-de-vitre.-le-bonheur-est-dans-la-maison-brielle-qui-lance-sa-propre-marque-de-charcuterie_dep-4222293_actu.Htm))

> Et après cette date, quelle suite pour le mouvement ? C'est ce que se demandaient déjà quelques personnes dans l'audience. « On prendra la décision en fonction de ce qui se passera le 7 mars », a répondu Marylise Léon. « Avant de se dire “c'est quoi la prochaine date ?”, c'est quoi la réponse du gouvernement ? », a-t-elle **temporisé**. -- ([source](https://www.lepoint.fr/societe/reforme-des-retraites-les-syndicats-veulent-casser-la-baraque-le-7-mars-03-03-2023-2510722_23.php))

> Jacqueline Galant suggère «un permis pour être parent» sur LN24: face à la polémique, elle **temporise**, «je lançais juste une réflexion...» -- ([source](https://www.sudinfo.be/id637107/article/2023-03-20/jacqueline-galant-suggere-un-permis-pour-etre-parent-sur-ln24-face-la-polemique))

> confie le coureur de la DSM dans L’Équipe, optimiste pour la reprise du Tour de France : « Mais je pense que ça va arriver. Dimanche, Ineos et Jumbo étaient en nombre. Je n'arrive pas à croire que (il **temporise**)... Bien sûr qu'il y aura du mouvement. ([source](https://le10sport.com/cyclisme/tour-de-france/tour-de-france-le-gros-coup-de-pression-de-bardet-a-pogacar-606793))

> Le responsable de la fondation Fayçal, Nabil Arab, lui, n’a pas cherché à le savoir. Il **temporise**: «Partager ces vidéos ne signifie rien». Pour Hafid Ouardiri, en revanche, «c’est très grave». «Un jeune qui diffuse ce type d’imagerie doit susciter notre plus grande vigilance». ([source](https://www.letemps.ch/suisse/suisse-alemanique/refus-serrer-main-dune-prof-therwil-signe-dune-derive))

Does that mean "replying with a delay". "waiting for the right moment to say something", "saying slowly" or anything else ?

Dictionaries are not very helpful on the matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All your examples showcase the [propensity](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/temporiser#Notes) for writers to confuse the meaning of [*temporiser*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/temporiser) (to wait for a more favorable moment) with that of [*tempérer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/temp%C3%A9rer) (to qualify, soften remarks, tone down, add a caveat: "temper").

I believe every single instance you provided should be construed using the latter meaning (*an artist/don't know that I'm really an artist; lasted a whole week last year/not necessarily this year; wish we had known each other earlier/the moment we met was the right time; what's the next step/first, what's the response; one should need a permit/just an idea*; the Tour de France example is not clear since there is ellipsis; *a child sharing war videos/sharing these doesn't mean anything*).

Comment: But `temporiser` yields `il temporise` whereas `tempérer` conjugates into `il tempère` (présent simple, both). Hence there is no confusion—and in any case two distinct verbs never yield the same conjugation (?). We should be able to determine which verb is intended. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah! You mean the writers, not the readers, are the ones that are confused.

Comment: cnrtl.fr's use cases of 'temporiser' = play for time.

Answer (score 1):

The basic meaning of **temporiser** is to slow down the tempo, the rythm of something.

In these particular cases, there is an implication that the first speaker is moving ahead too fast with their toughts and conclusions, to which the second speaker responds by telling them to slow down (reduce their tempo).

This commonly occurs in English as well, as in the idiom: "Hold on a minute!".

Answer (score 0):

**tempérer**, although I don't have the English equivalent, means that you try to balance the severity of the fact, the situation.

"*Tempérer une situation*" means that you try either to slow down an escalation, or try to increase the importance if the situation is left behind.

In your situation, with mostly conversations, is when a quoting is exaggerated (global warming in the second case), you try to bring some positive news.

HOWEVER. As said previously, it's a wrongly used word, but it's commonly used in French.

Comment: La question est à propos du verbe [« temporiser »](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/temporiser), non du verbe [« tempérer »](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/temp%C3%A9rer)